# how to stop live streaming pushed by obs studio

Tags: javascript, php, html, live

I was built a rmpt server successfully, and it worked well,but there is a thing, if here is a button which said 'stop the live' and users click on it will stop the live streaming.

My question is how to break the connection between rtmp server and obs studio?
I have already tried to delete the folder when clicked the 'stop live' botton,but the same folder created after and live is still streaming.

Comment: i never used this myself but after a bit of googling i found this https://github.com/obsproject/obs-websocket which looks like what you are looking for.

Comment: this fix will lead to some compatible issues, u can expect users to use right obs studio's version to fit obs-websocket's

Comment: there may be way to do this, https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/wiki/Control-module#Drop

Comment: i ran some tests and the method above is solved this problem.post here in case someone might be needed